# Count null values in each column of a table : PSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I have a very big table but as an example I will only provide a very small part of it as following:-

```
col1     col2     col3     col4
           10        2       12
  13        4                11
            0        1         
            3        5      111
```

I know how to find `null` values in one column. What I want to find is how many null values are there in each column just by writing one query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `COUNT(*)-COUNT(col1)` or `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE col1 IS NULL)`. Repeat for each column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an aggregate with a filter:

```
select count(*) filter (where col1 is null) as col1_nulls,
       count(*) filter (where col2 is null) as col2_nulls,
       count(*) filter (where col3 is null) as col3_nulls,
       count(*) filter (where col4 is null) as col4_nulls
from the_table;
```

Comment: Isn't there an easier way to do it? In my actual table I have 77 columns, so I don't want to write one line again and again.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question. But that's a one time thing to write, quite easily done with some copy & paste (and probably doesn't take longer that writing the question here on SO). If you need that query frequently, then just put it into a view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can generate this query on the fly. Here is an example of one way you can approach it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION null_counts(tablename text)
  RETURNS SETOF jsonb LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT to_jsonb(t) FROM (SELECT ' || (
    SELECT string_agg('count(*) filter (where ' || a.attname::text || ' is null) as ' || a.attname || '_nulls', ',')
    FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a 
    WHERE  a.attrelid = tablename::regclass
    AND    a.attnum > 0
    AND    a.attisdropped = false
    ) || ' FROM   ' || tablename::regclass || ') as t';
END
$func$; 

SELECT null_counts('your_table') AS val;
```